# How to override a method of a class from a gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, methods, overriding

I need to override the behavior of the `find` method of a class from a gem.

This is the code in the gem:

```
module Youtube
  class Display
    attr_accessor :base
    def find(id, options = {})
      detailed = convert_to_number(options.delete(:detailed))
      options[:detailed] = detailed unless detailed.nil?
      base.send :get, "/get_youtube", options.merge(:youtube_id => id)
    end
  end
end
```

How do I override the above `find` method in my own YoutubeSearch Controller of my Rails Application?

```
   def find(id, options = {})
    //Code here     
   end
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Create a .rb file in `config/initializers` directory with the following code:

```rb
Youtube::Display.class_eval do
  def find(id, options = {})
    # Code here     
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't this the same than just doing `class Youtube::Display ... end`?

Answer (score -2):

I have elaborated such a solution which **DOES NOT** require the Rails server restart after every code change (unlike all the other's solutions):

1.
Create **YoutubeHelper.rb**

```
module YoutubeHelper

  include Youtube

  def init_youtube_helper

    display.class_eval do
      def find(id, options = {})
      //Code here     
      end
    end

  end

end
```

2.
 **youtube_search_controller.rb**

```
class YoutubeSearchController < ActionController::Base
  include YoutubeHelper    
  before_action :init_youtube_helper   
end
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: what exactly more?

Comment: Yes, this approach is not effective - but I haven't found any better way. Put this code into initializers (like everybody do) is much worse (which means to restart the server upon every code change).