# Inherit controller class from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, shopify

I am using the `ShopifyApp` gem, which has an action called `receive` in its `WebhooksController`. As seen here: [Webhooks controller](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/blob/master/app/controllers/shopify_app/webhooks_controller.rb)

In my `WebhooksController` controller I am trying to override that `receive` action by doing the following:

```
class WebhooksController < ShopifyApp::WebhooksController
  def receive
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

My route to my `WebhooksController` is this:

```
webhooks_receive POST   /webhooks/receive(.:format)  webhooks#receive
```

And the route put in by the Gem engine is:

```
webhooks POST /webhooks/:type(.:format)  shopify_app/webhooks#receive
```

I see the data come in, but for some reason its not hitting my `receive` action and stopping at my `pry` and I'm not sure why.

[Found this and tried it, but no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688853/how-to-override-a-class-method-of-the-gem-in-rails-application)

[I tried this solution too and it didn't work..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668645/overriding-model-in-gem-adding-callback-and-methods)

Any thoughts?

Here are the top of my logs showing what's happening:

```
Started POST "/webhooks/receive" for XX.XXX.37.116 at 2016-04-21 14:57:02 
+0000
Cannot render console from XX.XXX.37.116! Allowed networks: XXX.0.0.1, ::1, 
127.0.0.0/127.XXX.XXX.255

ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* 
FROM "schema_migrations"

Processing by ShopifyApp::WebhooksController#receive as */*
Parameters: {"rate"=>{"origin"=>{"country"=>"US", "postal_code"=>"48615",   
"province"=>"MI", "city"=>"Breckenridge", "name"=>nil, "address1"=>"6760.. 
bunch of data removed for brevity}}}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `variable_size_secure_compare' for   
ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils:Module):
shopify_app (7.0.2) lib/shopify_app/webhook_verification.rb:20:in   
`hmac_valid?'
```

And my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'home#index'
mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/'
resources :store
resources :shipping_methods

post '/webhooks/receive', to: 'webhooks#receive'
post '/billing_plans', to: 'billing_plans#save_plan', as: 'save_plan'
get '/activate_charge', to: 'billing_plans#activate_charge', as: 'activate'
post '/create_charge', to: 'billing_plans#create_charge', as: 
'create_billing_plan'
```

Comment: **I see the data come in** - please explain where do you see this ? **but for some reason its not hitting my receive method and stopping at my pry and I'm not sure why** - Is it stopping at `binding.pry` ?

Comment: I see it in the console, and no its not hitting that `binding.pry` can't figure out why.. I tried this but it didn't work.. [Override class in Gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688853/how-to-override-a-class-method-of-the-gem-in-rails-application)

Comment: can you add logs ?

Comment: Heck I'll add my car if it will help! Updated the question with logs..

Comment: It looks as if the path is getting overriden by shopify, can you just add the routes file as well.

Comment: It is.. its the gem's engine that places those routes.. and they are all good, except for the webhook one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of troubleshooting I realized their Gemspec was including an old version of rails that did not contain the method they were calling..

I let them know and bumped my version from 4.2.5 to 4.2.6 and now it works.. frustrating but solved.. thanks everyone for your support!

If anyone else comes across this, in order to use the Shopify App gem Webhooks controller you will need to be running Rails 4.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting routes in this order:

```
post '/webhooks/receive', to: 'webhooks#receive'
mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

So in order for your own route to take precedence over the one that is defined in the `ShopifyApp` gem, you need to define it before mounting the `ShopifyApp` engine.

Moving your own route `post '/webhooks/receive', to: 'webhooks#receive'` before `mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/'` should fix the issue.

Refer to [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info.